# Is undefined a property of window/global?

Tags: javascript

It seems that the **undefined** is a property of window/global :

[image]

I always thought that **undefined** is, like **null**, a uniqe value in JavaScript.

But above code (*tested in Chrome*) make me confused.

Can some explain why

```
undefined in window
```

evalute to true, while

```
null in window
```

evaluate to false

Comment: relevant: /questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not only [`undefined`](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.9), but also [`Infinity`](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.22) and [`NaN`](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.23) are values of the [`global object`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1), in this case, `window` (as of [ES5.1 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)).

The fact you can't assign a value to `undefined` is because the property is defined with the `writable` [attribute](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1) set to `false`.

`null` is a [`primitive value`](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2) (as is `5`) of the [type](http://es5.github.io/#x8) `Null` (as is `Number` for `5`), not a property of `window`.

Take a look at the [annotated ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1) for more background on this, its quite readable!

Comment: Actually, before ES5, you can assign to `undefined`. You shouldn't but you can. And in fact there is code in jQuery that tries to get the real undefined in case anyone assigns stuff to undefined.

Comment: There is a built-in `undefined` value, which 'happens to be' used as the value of the `window.undefined` property (it's specified to be `undefined`, but in some implementations it can be reassigned). Very reliable ways to get the `undefined` value include `void 0`, `(function () {}())`, and `var undef;`. I recommend `var undef = void 0;` used inside a module-pattern scope.